# Log in Script not returning the values from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
there are three diffrent files all in php please help mysql doen't returns a value from the database ?        



//login.php
        <?php
        session_start();
        include("includes/html_codes.php");

        if (isset($_POST["email"])&&isset($_POST["password"])) {
          $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
          $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);

        if (!empty($username)&&!empty($password))  {



         $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=("$username") AND password=("$password")');

                $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
                $row = MySQL_fetch_row($query);
                if($row==1){
               echo 'ok';}  
           else {
          echo 'Wrong Username or Password';
          }


            } else {
           echo 'You must provide a username and password.';
           } }


        ?>

    ##i guess the query is incorrect please help new to php##

        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <html lang="en">


        <head>
            <title>Log in</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/register.css"/>

        </head>


        <body  style="background-color:#EEEEEE">

            <header>
            <?php topBarm(); ?>//some function which works perfectly
            </header>

            <div id="wrapperLogin">
            <center>


        <form id="generalForm" class="container" action="<?php echo $current_file; ?>" method="POST">
        <div class="field">Username: <input type="email" name="email" id ="email" class="input1"> </div> <div class="field">Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input1"></div></center>
        <center><div class="field"><input type="submit" class="buton" value="Log in" ></div>
        </form></center></html>


        ""<please read the index.php file also it contains some important stuff>"
```

index file is including all the files so i didn't need to include it in login.php

```
        //index.php
        <?php
        require 'includes/core.php';
        require 'includes/connect.php';

        include("login.php");

        echo $current_file;


         ?>






        ##connection is established with this file##
    >this code works perfectly
        //connect.php
        <?php
        $conn_error = 'Could not connect.';

        $mysql_host = 'localhost';
        $mysql_user = 'my_user';
        $mysql_pass = '';

        $mysql_db = 'my_database';

        if(!@mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass)||!@mysql_select_db($mysql_db)) {
          die(mysql_error());
          }

        echo 'Connected!'


        ?>
```

Comment: Login should never select fields which are not necessary. `SELECT *` with the proper exploit I will get username password and everything. Passwords should be also hashed before saving into database.

Comment: Please don't include comments in your code that might be interpreted as tags (i.e. `<please read...>`) also, what's with the keyboard mashing? If your question was actually of value, I've been put off simply by seeing that.

Comment: i can't echo ok(login.php). whenever i put email and username it says wrong username and password even when i enter the email and password which are in db.please help the above answers did'nt help if i use mysqli_query it gives me:Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lo.php on line 13 Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lo.php on line 15 Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lo.php on line 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is badly formed. Try

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='" . $username . "' AND password='" . $password . "');"
```

Also, note that the `mysql_` functions are deprecated. Update your code to `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: i can't echo ok(login.php). whenever i put email and username it says wrong username and password even when i enter the email and password which are in db.please help the above answers did'nt help if i use mysqli_query it gives me:Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lo.php on line 13 Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lo.php on line 15 Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lo.php on line 16

Answer (score 0):

First of all why do you have echos in the connection.php and why are you including so many files?

To learn basic debugging, you can do something like this with the result you are getting on your queries:

```
<pre>
<?php echo print_r($result) ?>
</pre>
```

Assuming you are doing a mysql_fetch_assoc or something similar with the result of the MySQL query

Answer (score 0):

the variable enclosed in single quotes will not be displayed

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'");
```

Comment: i can't echo ok(login.php). whenever i put email and username it says wrong username and password even when i enter the email and password which are in db.please help the above answers did'nt help

if i use mysqli_query it gives me:Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lo.php on line 13

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lo.php on line 15

Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lo.php on line 16

Comment: sorry it was my first time  asking ques here